# Cross merge by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to cross merge two dataframes but limiting the merge so only combinations within the same group are provided. The pandas documentation says `When performing a cross merge, no column specifications to merge on are allowed`. At the moment to achieve this I'm using a for loop and concatenating the resulting dfs but is there a more efficient way?

Example input data:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'field_a': ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'papaya']
})

df2  = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'field_b': ['apple', 'strawberry', 'coconut', 'papaya']
})
```

Example required output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
             'field_a': ['apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'banana', 'banana', 'papaya', 'papaya'],
             'field_b': ['apple', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'strawberry', 'coconut', 'papaya', 'coconut', 'papaya']})
```

Current approach:

```
cols = ['group', 'field_a', 'field_b']
all_possible_matches = pd.DataFrame({
        col: [] for col in cols
    })
for group in [1, 2]:
    combined = df1[df1['group'] == group].merge(df2[df2['group'] == group][['field_b']], how='cross')
    all_possible_matches = pd.concat([all_possible_matches, combined])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cross-merge by group would be equivalent to a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the group:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='group')

# if "group" is the only common column
# out = df1.merge(df2)
```

Output:

```
   group field_a     field_b
0      1   apple       apple
1      1   apple  strawberry
2      1    pear       apple
3      1    pear  strawberry
4      2  banana     coconut
5      2  banana      papaya
6      2  papaya     coconut
7      2  papaya      papaya
```

Before `how='cross'` was available in pandas, a way to perform a cross-merge was actually to add a dummy key and merge on that:

```
# before
df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1
df1.merge(df2, on='key').drop(columns=['key'])

# now
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Comment: Oh nice, I hadn't considered it that way! Looks really obvious now, thank you!